# Django give permissions to users per company

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, authorization

In my case I have different users which can be part of different companies. An user can belong to multiple companies and a company has multiple customers, products, services, …

Now I want the user to be able to have different permissions per company. So let’s say user X can manage the customers in company A but can only read the products and services. And user X can manage the users, products and services in company B.

I would like to work with roles: so manage everything would be the role “superadmin” and manage customers but read products and services would be the role “sales” for example.

So in short: I want to create roles where I can assing permssions to and then add these roles to users per company.

I am planning on using [rsinger86/drf-access-policy](https://github.com/rsinger86/drf-access-policy) to manage access control but any suggestions are welcome.

Please suggest me a good way to accomplish this scenario. How am I able to add roles per company and am I still able to use the by-default-generated auth_permissions from Django?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You can just create groups and check if the user belong to that group and do neccessary actions

Comment: With 'groups' do you mean the Django auth groups? And I would llike the user to have different permissions in different companies, so how would you handle this?

Comment: You can assign a user in multiple groups so check if the user belongs to corresponding group.

Comment: So I would create a group for every single company?

Comment: How is each company being stored in your application? Is there a company model which every other model (user, product, customer, etc) has a relationship with?